# How to sum the result of calculated field on Excel's Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, custom-fields

I'm working on a pivot table with some data that I want to round up. My pivot table currently has 1 text field for the rows and 2 numeric fields for the values. The field "Field 1" has the original numeric values from the data source, which contain decimals. I want all those values to be rounded up to integers, so I created a calculated field for the pivot table with the following formula: `=ROUNDUP([Field 1], 0)`. The calculated field is named "Field 2". The formula effectively rounds up all values. However, the sum is not doing what I expect.

I'm attaching a screenshot to show this better:

[image: Example pivot table].

What I want to do is to round up all original values and then add up all those new values. In the example, the result should return 2 in the totals row (1+1). However, what Excel is doing is first adding up all the values, which give a result of 0.83, and then rounding that result to 1.

I would appreciate any suggestions to fix this, whether through some pivot table option that I am missing or using VBA code. It is not possible to just round up the values in the source table since they are used for other calculations that would mess up if the pivot table data is filtered.

I already tried modifying the field options for the calculated field, playing around to show the max, min, sum, and other options. I also tried to sum up all the `DataBodyRange` of the pivot table in a different cell to get the result but I could not manage to get a dynamic reference. I could just do something like `=SUM("A1:A2")` which is static and will not automatically sum new data.

Comment: I believe this has been an Excel problem, acknowledged by Microsoft, that affects versions at least since 2010. One method of obtaining your desired results would be to use Power Query and grouping; then add a custom column to do the Rounded Sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change the way how to calculate Roundup on pivottable total row. But you can sum it with VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetTotal()
    Dim fld As PivotField
    Const HEADERNAME = "Sum of Field2"
    Application.Volatile
    Set fld = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).DataFields(HEADERNAME)
    GetTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(fld.DataRange)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was out of the office for a few days. This is just what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to `RoundUp` the results of `Field1` and  be able to SUM those correctly.

*Note that if you really want to round up each member of Field 1 and SUM that, your Field 2 sum will depend in part on how many entries you have. If that is what you really want, a minor code change will accomplish that*

Here is a Power Query solution

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Source Data***
[image]

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual Data source data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],

//Change next line to reflect actual column names
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ab", type text}, {"f1", type number}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ab"}, {

//Change new column names in each aggregation to reflect what you wanbt
        {"Sum of Field 1", each List.Sum([f1]), type nullable number}, 
        {"Sum of Field 2", each Number.RoundUp(List.Sum([f1])), type nullable number}
        }),

//Add a Totals Row if you wish, or enable it from the Worksheet if you prefer
    #"Add Totals Row" = 
    Table.InsertRows(
        #"Grouped Rows",
        Table.RowCount(#"Grouped Rows"),
        {Record.FromList(
            {"Grand Total"}
            & {List.Sum(#"Grouped Rows"[Sum of Field 1])}
            & {List.Sum(#"Grouped Rows"[Sum of Field 2])},
            Table.ColumnNames(#"Grouped Rows"))})
in 
    #"Add Totals Row"
```

*After Saving to a worksheet, be sure to select the `Totals` option from the Table Design interface if you have not included that row in your `M Code`*

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! While this works perfectly, I found out that Power Query is not available in Excel for Mac. That is a problem since I need full compatibility with all systems. I will need to use VBA code as a workaround. Thank you for your time Ron.